# Inline transform specific attributes in JSON payload containing nested arrays and objects of key/value pairs

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have an input payload that I need to pass through directly to the output except for specific date attributes which I need to transform. These date attributes can be anywhere within the payload. i.e.,

1. as key/value pairs
2. as key/value pairs within an object
3. as key/value pairs within an array
4. as key/value pairs within an object in an array

I have addressed cases 1 and 2 above with the dataweave code below. However, I am a little stuck with cases 3 and 4. Would very much appreciate any pointers in this regard. Thanks!

Input payload:

```
{
   "key1":"value1",
   "key2":"value2",
   "arrayList1":[
      {
         "key3":"value3",
         "datefield_1":"13/01/2006",
         "datefield_2":"15/06/1980",
         "arrayList2":[
            {
               "key4":"value4",
               "datefield_3":"13/01/2000",
               "datefield_4":"15/06/2003",
               "arrayList2":[
                  {
                     "key5":"value5",
                     "datefield_5":"30/01/2000",
                     "datefield_6":"14/06/2003"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "key6":"value6",
         "datefield_7":"20/02/2000"
      }
   ]
}
```

Dataweave code:

```
%dw 1.0
 %output application/json
 %var keysToUpdate = ['datefield_1', 'datefield_2', 'datefield_3', 'datefield_4', 'datefield_5', 'datefield_6', 'datefield_7']
 %function transformDateFormat(inputDate) inputDate as :date {format: "dd/MM/yyyy"} as :date {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"}
 %function findKey(key) keysToUpdate contains key
 %function changePayload(input) input mapObject ({
     ($$): changePayload($) when $ is :object otherwise $
     } unless findKey($$ as :string) otherwise {
     ($$): transformDateFormat($)
 })
 ---
 changePayload (payload)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `match` operator with some recursion will be helpful here.

Try this out. I created a function, `applyToValuesWhenKey`, that takes in the input value as `e`, a function to apply to the values as `fn`, and a function that returns a boolean that will dictate whether or not to apply `fn` to the value called `predicate`. It uses recursion and the `match` operator to loop through the data, applying `map`, `mapObject`, or just returning the given value depending on whether or not the current value is an object, array, or anything else. The rest is your code:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json

%var input = {
   "key1":"value1",
   "key2":"value2",
   "arrayList1":[
      {
         "key3":"value3",
         "datefield_1":"13/01/2006",
         "datefield_2":"15/06/1980",
         "arrayList2":[
            {
               "key4":"value4",
               "datefield_3":"13/01/2000",
               "datefield_4":"15/06/2003",
               "arrayList2":[
                  {
                     "key5":"value5",
                     "datefield_5":"30/01/2000",
                     "datefield_6":"14/06/2003"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "key6":"value6",
         "datefield_7":"20/02/2000"
      }
   ]
}

%var keysToUpdate = [ 'datefield_1', 'datefield_2', 'datefield_3', 'datefield_4', 'datefield_5', 'datefield_6', 'datefield_7' ]

%function applyToValuesWhenKey( e, fn, predicate )
  e match {
    :array  -> $ map applyToValuesWhenKey( $, fn, predicate ),
    :object -> $ mapObject ( ( v, k ) -> { 
                             ( k ): fn( v )
                           } when predicate( k ) otherwise {
                             ( k ): applyToValuesWhenKey( v, fn, predicate )
                           }
                         ),
    default -> $
  }

%function transformDateFormat( date ) 
  date as :date { format: "dd/MM/yyyy" } as :date { format: "yyyy-MM-dd" }

%function transformDates( input )
  applyToValuesWhenKey( input, 
                        transformDateFormat,
                        ( ( key ) -> keysToUpdate contains ( key as :string ) ) )
---
transformDates( input )
```